# How can I apply filter or another query on the value calculated in elasticsearch query?

Tags: elasticsearch

```
GET urza/user/_search
{
“script_fields”: {
“my_score”: {
“script”: “doc[‘total_revenue_i’].value / doc[‘purchased_i’].value”
}
},“query”: {
“range”: {
“total_revenue_i”: {
“gt”:0
}
}
}
}
```

How can I apply a filter on my_score value that will be calculated in above query?

Comment: Script fields are computed after the fetch phase, so that's not possible.

Comment: Is their any other way to apply a arithmetic operation on two fields and then use that value inside filter or query ??

Comment: Yes, you can do that computation at indexing time and then store the result in a new field. ES is not afraid of that and you shouldn't be either.

Comment: other then making more fields is their any way of computing such result or making fields will be the best way to do so.

Comment: Creating a new field is the best way to do it. You should always index your data so as to make your searching and aggregating queries as optimal as it gets.